# Paypal express Button is Missing

Tags: opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.6 that came with the PayPal Express Checkout module. I installed it, filled in the API details, changed the status to "enabled", changed the Order Status to the logical things (Completed Status: to Complete, Denied Status: to Denied, etc.) and saved it.

But the button "Confirm Order" does not show. If I choose an other Payment Method (iDEAL in my case) the button is showing. I already checked if it is the Theme I am using, but when I switch to default theme it's the same. In Chrome. Firefox and Safari, no button with PayPal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Admin panel->Extension->Modules->Paypal Express checkout module, Install and add there module row where button should be shown (pick layout page, position, Enabled etc) and Save.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the API details in Extension >Payments >PayPal Express Checkout.